# MVC form multipart/form-data isnt rendering correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

here is my view. I am attempting to have a file upload control.

```
@section termimalContent {
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Terminals_Policies", "multipart/form-data"))
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h2>
            Create new policy</h2>
      </legend>
      <p>
        <strong>Assigning devices to Node:</strong> @Model.GroupName</p>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PolicyName)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PolicyName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PolicyName)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PolicyType)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItems, new SelectList(Model.PolicyType, "Value", "Text"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItems)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="file1">
          Filename:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
      </div>
      <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="file2">
          Filename:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />
      </div>
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupId)
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupName)
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  }
}
```

but the html is being rendered as:

```
<form action="/Terminals_Policies/Add/1?Length=19" id="form0" method="post">
```

Anyone know what i have done wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Terminals_Policies", FormMethod.Post,new{enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
```

As it should be in the format

```
Html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})
```

Comment: Thanks, but this renders as <form action="/Terminals_Policies/Add/1?enctype=multipart%2Fform-data" id="form0" method="post">

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I should have rerad some documentation rather than the monkey at a type writer approach! Will accept this answer